# og image is not working while link sharing

Tags: html

I am using following html tags for og

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="https://infinitybulksms.in"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="INFINITY BULK SMS" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="India's most reliable BULK SMS service. | Transactional SMS | Promotional SMS | 6 Character Sender ID" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://infinitybulksms.in/img/logo.JPG" />    
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="550" />
```

But while sharing url link, desired image is not showing even description also.

Why its not working?

Comment: Where is this not working? Facebook? You might need to refresh this link on their developer's console if the HTML is new.

Comment: Share this link, https://infinitybulksms.in on facebook. You can see the preview. That is not desired content.

Comment: Any idea, anyone???

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will cache `og` information and changes you made to the HTML, and the `og` tags can take a while to be applied.

In order to force this, let's call it reindex, you can enter the URL in the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) and it will request the page as is currently and update how the link appears.